# Python - Discord login and join server

Tags: python

im trying to make a script which makes 2 or more accounts to login and join a server.
what i have found is this

```
import requests
#base url
url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/{}"
#headers, add more headers to make sure you dont get banned by discord for automating, you can see your headers by pressing ctrl+shift+i and going to the networks tab.
headers = {
    "Authorization":"your token here"
}

r = requests.post(url.format("your invite code"), headers=headers, json={})
print(r.status_code) #prints 200 if all went well
```

so if you have any idea what i have to do i would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're aiming to do here, but from what I can tell you want to execute this code some x number of times. The comments advise you to add multiple headers, so just fill out the headers for the different authorization tokens for the number of times you want to make a post request, throw that into a for loop, and of course you're going to have to fill out the parameters yourself.

```
import requests
#base url
url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/{}"
#headers, add more headers to make sure you dont get banned by discord for automating, you can see your headers by pressing ctrl+shift+i and going to the networks tab.
headers = [{"Authorization":"your token here"}, {"Authorization":"your second token here"}]
for header in headers:
    r = requests.post(url.format("your invite code"), headers=header, json={})
    print(r.status_code) #prints 200 if all went well
```